# What is default timeout for MongoDB operation (CRUD and aggregate)?

Tags: mongodb

I didn't find information about what is default value for executing operation in MongoDB. Some of my aggregate commands takes minutes (very large reports). It is OK for me to waiting this time, but I'm afraid to get error.

I know, that I can set it. But a lots of my software users use their own servers. Of course with default settings.

Answer (score 2):

Until [this feature](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2212) is implemented, this will essentially be a driver/client level setting.  The query will run until completion on the server, though eventually it might timeout a cursor - see the [cursorinfo command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/cursorInfo/#cursorinfo) for more there.

To figure out what your settings are you will need to consult your relevant driver documentation.  There may be multiple settings that apply based on what you are looking for, like the [various options](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-user/dq6GRHCIyq8) in the Java driver, for example.

Comment: Note that the feature has been implemented--it made it to 2.6.0.